# Configurable Map Viewer css.JS problem on Chrome

Tags: dojo, configurable-map-viewer, css

I have a problem in displaying my map. It runs fine on IE, but it cant even load on Chrome (blank white page as if nothing is executed).

I find the problem in some css files : load-css.js and css.js. The error is : "Uncaught ReferenceError: normal is not defined". [Click Here for the screenshot of the erro](https://snag.gy/j5GReb.jpg)r. The error is at **line 15 (js.css)** and **lines 59, 82, 4:373 (for load-js.css)**

Here is the code for the **js.css** :

```
    //>>built
define("xstyle/css", ["require"], function(g) {
    function h(a, b, d) {
        var e = document.documentElement;
        a = e.insertBefore(document.createElement(a), e.firstChild);
        a.id = b;
        b = (a.currentStyle || getComputedStyle(a, null))[d];
        e.removeChild(a);
        return b
    }
    return {
        load: function(a, b, d, e) {
            function f() {
                var a = h("x-parse", null, "content");
                a && "none" != a ? b([eval(a)], d) : d()
            }
            var k = b.toUrl(a)
              , c = b.cache["url:" + k];
            if (c)
                return c.xCss && (c = c.cssText),
                g(["./util/createStyleSheet"], function(a) {
                    a(c)
                }),
                f();
            if ("none" == h("div", a.replace(/\//g, "-").replace(/\..*/, "") + "-loaded", "display"))
                return f();
            g(["./load-css"], function(a) {
                a(k, f)
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the code for load-js.css

```
//>>built
define("xstyle/load-css", [], function() {
    function r(a, b) {
        var d = a[s]("link");
        d.rel = "stylesheet";
        d.type = "text/css";
        b && (d.href = b);
        return d
    }
    function t(a) {
        a = a.split("!");
        for (var b, d = 1; b = a[d++]; )
            b = b.split("\x3d", 2),
            a[b[0]] = 2 == b.length ? b[1] : !0;
        return a
    }
    function u(a) {
        if (g["dom-create-style-element"])
            return b = document.createElement("style"),
            b.setAttribute("type", "text/css"),
            b.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a)),
            m.insertBefore(b, m.firstChild),
            b;
        var b = document.createStyleSheet();
        b.cssText = a;
        return b.owningElement
    }
    var n = "onreadystatechange"
      , p = "onload"
      , s = "createElement"
      , q = !1
      , e = document
      , v = "undefined" == typeof _css_cache ? {} : _css_cache
      , g = {
        "event-link-onload": null === document.createElement("link").onload && !navigator.userAgent.match(/AppleWebKit/),
        "dom-create-style-element": !document.createStyleSheet
    }
      , m = e.head || (e.head = e.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]);
    if (!g["bundled-css"])
        var w = function(a, b) {
            function d(c) {
                if (c = c.sheet || c.styleSheet)
                    for (var a = document.styleSheets, b = a.length; 0 < b; b--)
                        if (a[b - 1] == c)
                            return !0
            }
            function h(c, a) {
                d(c.link) ? (e(c),
                a()) : q || setTimeout(function() {
                    h(c, a)
                }, c.wait)
            }
            function e(a) {
                a = a.link;
                a[n] = a[p] = null
            }
            function l() {
                k || (k = !0,
                b())
            }
            require.onError && (require.onError = function(a) {
                return function() {
                    q = !0;
                    a.apply(this, arguments)
                }
            }(require.onError));
            var k;
            (function(a, b) {
                var d = a.link;
                d[n] = d[p] = function() {
                    if (!d.readyState || "complete" == d.readyState)
                        g["event-link-onload"] = !0,
                        e(a),
                        b()
                }
            }
            )(a, l);
            g["event-link-onload"] || h(a, l)
        };
    return function(a, b, d) {
        for (var h = a.split(","), g = h.length, l = function() {
            0 == --g && b(f.sheet || f.styleSheet)
        }, k = 0; k < h.length; k++) {
            a = h[k];
            var c = v[a];
            if (c)
                return f = u(c),
                l();
            a = t(a);
            var c = a.shift()
              , c = c.lastIndexOf(".") <= c.lastIndexOf("/") ? c + ".css" : c
              , f = r(e);
            a = "nowait"in a ? "false" != a.nowait : !(!d || !d.cssDeferLoad);
            w({
                link: f,
                url: c,
                wait: d && d.cssWatchPeriod || 25
            }, l);
            a && b(f);
            f.href = c;
            m.appendChild(f)
        }
    }
});
```

I host the script locally : http://local_add/folder/arcgis_js_api/library/3.15/3.15/xstyle/css.js and /3.15/3.15/xstyle/load-css.js. These files are still original.

How can i fix this so that i can run it on chrome ?

Comment: Pictures of error messages are always problematic, and pictures of error messages on external sites even more so. Just tell us what it says, or at least upload the image here so it doesn't disappear or redirect to an extortion malware site when we least expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution here : https://community.esri.com/thread/177937

In css.js, search for the following text -

a&&"none"!=a

and replace it with -

a&&"none"!=a&&"normal"!=a

Problem is gone.

Comment: No need to modify the Esri source and that is not a good practice. The fix you mention was a temporary workaround to an issue with the Esri JavaScript API back in 2016. It was fixed quickly and newer versions of the API do not have this issue.